# Show: $\int_{\Omega} f d\mu =\int_{]0,\infty[} \mu(E_t) d\lambda_1(t)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I have troubles understanding one step in the solution for this task:

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure and $f:\Omega \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ be a measurable function. Let $E_t:=\{\omega \in \Omega: f(\omega)>t \}$ for each $t>0$. Prove that $$\int_{\Omega} f d\mu =\int_{]0,\infty[} \mu(E_t) d\lambda_1(t)$$

Solution: 
Note that $f$ is a nonnegative measurable function and for all $t>0$,
$$\mu(E_t)=\int_{\Omega} \chi_{\{f(\omega)>t\}} \mu(d\omega)$$

Therefore by Tonelli:
$$\int_{]0,\infty[} \mu(E_t) d\lambda_1(t)=\int_{\Omega} \left( \int_{]0,\infty[}\chi_{\{f(\omega)>t\}}  d\lambda_1(t)\right) \mu(d\omega)$$

Now here is the step I don't understand:
$$\int_{\Omega} \left( \int_{]0,\infty[}\chi_{\{f(\omega)>t\}}  d\lambda_1(t)\right) \mu(d\omega)=\int_{\Omega} \left( \int_{]0,f(\omega)[} d\lambda_1\right) \mu(d\omega)$$

How do I get these integral limits $]0,f(\omega)[$?

I know that

$$\int_{\Omega} \left( \int_{]0,\infty[}\chi_{\{f(\omega)>t\}}  d\lambda_1(t)\right) \mu(d\omega)=\int_{\Omega} \left( \int_{\{f(\omega)>t\}} d\lambda_1\right) \mu(d\omega)$$

and that $\{f(\omega)>t\}=f^{-1}((t,\infty))=E_t$ but how do I get $]0,f(\omega)[$ as the inner integral limits?

My second question is rather short and more general:

Does the notation $\lambda_2(x,y)$ mean that the integral should be done in order, meaning integrated with respect to $x$ first and then with respect to $y$ or does that just mean that we integrate over both without including an order?

Comment: Where is the notation $\lambda_2$ defined?

Comment: It's not in the task and $\lambda_2$ is just the 2-dimensional Lebesgue measure. I just meant in general when I have a Lebesgue integral of the form: $\int d\lambda_2(x,y)$

Comment: I would presume that $\lambda_2$ is the 2 dimensional Lebesque measure, and integrating with respect to $\lambda_2$ just means integrating directly with $\lambda_2$. If you want to replace the integral with an interated integral, you need to invoke Fubini/Tonelli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $1_{ \{ w | f(w) >s \} } (x) = 1_{ \{ t| f(x) > t \} } (s) = 1_{ [0,f(x)) } (s)$.